# New System Versioned tables created on their own?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, I have System Versioned tables of my Dimension tables, IE: `Dim.Entity` with a named history table called `Dim.EntityHistory`. However, I've noticed recently that on a few of these tables, SQL Server has seemingly made new System Versioned tables on its own (IE: `MSSQL_TemporalHistoryFor_12928938`) and "kicked" my named history tables out into the general table area. Does anyone have any insight into why this happened? From what I understand in the documentation, if you update the table schema, the change is propagated to the history table automatically (I initially thought this might be why this happened).

I am running on SQL Server 2019 / Azure.

Comment: Are you disabling and re-enabling system versioning at any point?

Comment: Hmm, I might've now that you mention it to truncate a table then renabled it. Do you think that might've caused it?

Comment: When you create a temporal table you either provide the name of the history table yourself or let it generate automatically. Your name is not remembered, after you disable system versioning your history table is just a regular table, you have to completely specify the name again to continue using it or you'll get an auto-generated new history table.

Comment: That looks to be exactly what happened. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Stu for the answer above. I actually found in the documentation where they describe exactly what you need to do. To solve the problem for my example above:

```
BEGIN TRY

   BEGIN TRAN

   ALTER TABLE Dim.EntityName SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);
   --Do Activity here IE: Truncate
   ALTER TABLE Dim.Entity SET
   (
      SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = Dim.EntityHistory)
   );

   COMMIT TRAN;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK;

  SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

END CATCH;
```

Adapted from the article below:

> When turning system versioning back on, do not forget to specify the HISTORY_TABLE argument. Failing to do so will result in a new history table being created and associated with the current table. The original history table will still exist as a normal table, but won't be associated with the current table.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/stopping-system-versioning-on-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver15